# Find all numbers x which satisfy $|x^2 + 2| = |x^2 − 11|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

This question is taken from book: Exercises and Problems in Calculus, by
John M. Erdman, available [online](http://web.pdx.edu/~erdman/CALCULUS/CALCULUS_pdf.pdf), from chapter 1.1, question $4$.

Request help, as not clear if my approach is correct.

> (4) Find all numbers x which satisfy $|x^2 + 2| = |x^2 − 11|$.

Have two conditions, leading to three intervals;
(i) $x \lt \sqrt{-2}$
(ii) $\sqrt{-2} \le x \lt \sqrt{11}$
(iii) $x \ge \sqrt{11}$

(i) no soln.
(ii) $2x^2 = 9 \implies x = \pm\sqrt{\frac 92}$
(iii) no soln.

Verifying:
First, the two solutions must satisfy that they lie in the given interval,
this means $\sqrt{-2} \le x \lt \sqrt{11}\implies \sqrt{2}i \le x \lt \sqrt{11}$.

Am not clear, as the lower bound is not a real one. So, given the two real values of $x = \pm\sqrt{\frac 92}$ need only check with the upper bound.

For further verification, substitute in values of $x$, for interval (ii):
a) For $x = \sqrt{\frac 92}$, $|x^2 + 2| = |x^2 − 11|$ leads to
$\frac 92 + 2 = -\frac 92 + 11\implies 2\frac 92 = 9$.

b) For $x = -\sqrt{\frac 92}$, $|x^2 + 2| = |x^2 − 11|$ leads to
$\frac 92 + 2 = -\frac 92 + 11\implies 2\frac 92 = 9$.

Comment: Is $x$ meant to be real?   Your argument appears to suggest that $x$ might be complex.  Though it is not clear what you might mean by $x<\sqrt {-2}$, for instance.

Comment: Well, if $x$ can be complex you should state that.  The posted solutions both assume that $x\in \mathbb R$.

Comment: @lulu Please provide answer considering the complex domain for $x$.

Comment: For complex $x$, the possible $x^2$ are the set of points in the plane equidistant from $(-2,0)$ and $(11,0)$.  That't the vertical line passing through the midpoint, $(\frac 92,0)$.  Then, of course, you want the two square roots of every point on that line.

Comment: @jiten Your question implies that $x \in \Bbb R$.  The $\lt$ relation doesn't make sense if the domain is $\Bbb C.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not correct. But contains good ideas. 
You write $\sqrt{2}i\leq x\leq \sqrt{11}$. 
You can not do that, because you can not order complex numbers! So that is a mistake.
Also it is not clear, how you get your three conditions, which are also the wrong intervals.

It is $x^2+2>0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
So $|x^2+2|=x^2+2$.

Now: $|x^2-11|=\begin{cases} -x^2+11, \sqrt{11}\geq x\geq-\sqrt{11}\\ x^2-11, x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\sqrt{11},\sqrt{11})\end{cases}$

Now seperate the cases and check, if

> $x^2+2=-x^2+11$ has solutions in $(-\sqrt{11},\sqrt{11})$

or

> $x^2+2=x^2-11$ has solutions in $\mathbb{R}\setminus (-\sqrt{11},\sqrt{11})$

For the first equation, you get $2x^2=9\Leftrightarrow x_{1,2}=\sqrt{\frac92}\in (-\sqrt{11},\sqrt{11})$

The second equation has obviously no solutions, because it is equivalent to $2=-11$.

Comment: If consider $x \in \mathbb{C}$, then what would be the changes to your solution.

Comment: Please provide response to my last comment.

Comment: @jiten If you really want to consider $x\in\mathbb{C}$, then you can use, that the absolute value of a complex number is defined by $|a+ib|=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So you write $x=a+ib$ and then solve $|a+ib+2|=|a+ib-11|$.

Comment: Which leads to $\sqrt{(a+2)^2+b^2}=\sqrt{(a-11)^2+b^2}$

Comment: It leads to $\sqrt{a^2+4+4a+b^2} = \sqrt{a^2+121-22a+b^2}$. Squaring both sides: $a^2+4+4a+b^2 = a^2+121-22a+b^2\implies 26a = 117\implies a=9/2$. But, how to find $b$? Need distance from the equidistant (perpendicular bisector of the line joining the two points) line for that. Half of the distance between the given points is $=\frac{\sqrt{13}}{2}$. Now, $b^2 = \frac{13}{4} - \frac{81}4 = -\frac{68}{4}$. So, $b = \sqrt{17}i$. Verifying $\sqrt{(\frac {13}{4})^2 -17} = \sqrt{(\frac {-13}{4})^2 -17}$.

Comment: Please vet my last comment.

Comment: You should keep the expressions and not expand them. That makes it easier. After squaring the equation, which can be done since both expressions are always positiv, you get: $(a+2)^2+b^2=(a-11)^2+b^2$. You see, that $b^2$ cancels each other out. So we are left with $(a+2)^2=(a-11)^2\Leftrightarrow (a+2)^2-(a-11)^2=0$. With the binomial formula, we get: $(a+2-a+11)(a+2+a-11)=0$. So $22(2a-9)=0$.So $a=\frac92$. b does not matter in this calculation. Every complex number of the form: $\frac92+ib$ is a solution to the equation.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps simpler (fewer cases to distinguish):

Note that $|a|=|b|$ (with real numbers $a,b$) means that $a=b$ or $a=-b$.
So here either $x^2+2=x^2-11$, which is absurd, or $x^2+2=-(x^2-11)$, which leads to $2x^2=9$ and so $$x=\pm\frac 32\sqrt 2.$$

Verification: If $x=\pm\frac32\sqrt 2$, then $x^2=\frac 92$ and $|x^2+2|=|\frac{13}2|=\frac{13}2$ and $|x^2-11|=|\frac92-11|=|-\frac{13}2|=\frac{13}2$ as well.

Answer (score 1):

$\mathrm{dist}(x^2,-2)=|x^2+2|=|x^2-11|=\mathrm{dist}(x^2,11)$. Therefore you want $x^2$ to be equidistant from $-2$ and $11$, i.e. $x^2=11-\frac{\mathrm{dist}(-2,11)}{2}=-2+\frac{\mathrm{dist}(-2,11)}{2}=\frac{9}{2}$. It follows that $x=\pm \frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: $dist(-2,11)=13$

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{dist}(x^2,-2) = \mathrm{dist}(-x^2,2)$ and $\mathrm{dist}(x^2,11) = \mathrm{dist}(-x^2,-11)$, so you have to be careful of which ones are appropriate to use.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

For real $x,$ $x^2\ge0$, so $x^2+2>0$, so $|x^2+2|=x^2+2$.  $|x^2-11|=x^2-11$ or $-(x^2-11).$  Equate them and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe another approach might also be interesting:

$$|x^2 +2| = |x^2-11| \Leftrightarrow (x^2+2)^2 = (x^2-11)^2\Leftrightarrow (x^2+2)^2 - (x^2-11)^2 = 0$$
$$\stackrel{a^2-b^2 = (a-b)(a+b)}{\Leftrightarrow} (x^2+2 - (x^2-11))(x^2 + 2 + x^2-11)= 13(2x^2 - 9)= 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^2= \frac{9}{2}\Leftrightarrow x= \pm\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$$